# Как удалять checked="checked"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<span class="input_type_radio">
  <input type="radio" name="productitem_20631-jshop_attr_id[1]" id="productitem_20631_jshop_attr_id14" value="4" checked="checked" onclick="notUseAttrValue('1', this.value);" /> 
  <label for="productitem_20631_jshop_attr_id14">
    <span class="radio_attr_label">
      <img data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Черный" src="/black.png" alt="">
      <span>Выбранный цвет: Черный</span>
    </span>
  </label>
</span>
```

Как убрать `checked="checked"`? (Который ставится автоматически)

Comment: document.innerHtml = document.innerHtml.split('checked="checked"').join()

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста куда это прописать?

Comment: На событие после загрузки окна либо добавить в скрипт после рендера страницы

Answer (score 1):

У элемента же есть id... Можно прямо так и записать где-нибудь в конце страницы:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("productitem_20631_jshop_attr_id14").checked = false;
</script>
```

А можно отключить сразу все радио:

```js
for (let radio of document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]')) {
  radio.checked = false;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" checked="true">
<input type="radio" checked="true">
<input type="radio" checked="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте своим `input` атрибут [`autocomplete="off"`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/autocomplete) - он даёт браузеру запомнить предыдущий выбор пользователя.
Т.е. после перезагрузки статус `input` будет таким, каким указан в **HTML**.

Пример использования:

```
<span class="input_type_radio">
  <!-- При загрузке старницы инпут будет активный, т.к. присутствует атрибут checked="checked" -->
  <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="productitem_20631-jshop_attr_id[1]" id="productitem_20631_jshop_attr_id14" value="4" checked="checked" onclick="notUseAttrValue('1', this.value);"/> 
  <label for="productitem_20631_jshop_attr_id14">
    <span class="radio_attr_label">
      <img data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Черный" src="/black.png" alt="">
      <span>Выбранный цвет: Черный</span>
    </span>
  </label>
</span>
```